# Merge CSS declarations in one, possible?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I am trying to face a little problem i have encountered with.

I am designing a map in leaflet. What i want to achieve is add a HTML label above each marker in a leaflet map, like in this photoshoped example:

[image]

Ok the code for each label to display it is:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="red"></td>
        <td class="yellow"></td>
        <td class="orange"></td>
        <td class="blue"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{    
    padding:20px;
    border:5px solid black;
}
.red{
    background-color:#F15E66;
}
.yellow{
    background-color:#FFDB64;
}
.orange{
    background-color:#F58326;
}
.blue{
    background-color:#85B1DE;
}
```

check https://jsfiddle.net/YameenYasin/cx1ka3Ly/ for the live code.

Ok the problem comes when leaflet labels only allow to add one unique CSS entry for each label. Example:

```
marker.bindLabel('<table><tr><td class="red"></td><td class="yellow"></td><td class="orange"></td><td class="blue"></td></tr></table>',
    {noHide: true, className: "onlyone", offset: [-10, -40] });
```

Notice the className: "onlyone" property. I can only put one css there and the "class" tags added in the html code are not executed (they do not work).

My conclusion is that i need to add all the CSS code in only one classname called "onlyone" so that then i can do className: "onlyone".

Is this possible?

Regards,

Comment: Can you show us what HTML/CSS is actually rendered? You can find that out in the inspector.

Comment: What is happening when you execute this code? Is '<table><tr><td class="red"></td><td class="yellow"></td><td class="orange"></td><td class="blue"></td></tr></table>' Not being added to the marker?

Where are you seeing the class "onlyone" being added?

Comment: @ChrisJ i can see the "onlyone" class in the map in each label, but the red, yellow, orange and blue classes are not displayed.

Comment: Does leaflet like HTML in labels?

Comment: Its going into each label? Does the bindLabel method allow a callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to add a single class to the `tr` and then target the children by 'number' using `nth-child` as follows.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
.multi td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #F15E66;
}
.multi td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #FFDB64;
}
.multi td:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #F58326;
}
.multi td:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #85B1DE;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="multi">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:
https://jsfiddle.net/cx1ka3Ly/2/

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{    
    padding:20px;
    border:5px solid black;
}
.onlyone:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#F15E66;
}
.onlyone:nth-child(2){
    background-color:#FFDB64;
}
.onlyone:nth-child(3){
    background-color:#F58326;
}
.onlyone:nth-child(4){
    background-color:#85B1DE;
}
```